# Kmeans matlab "Empty cluster created at iteration 1" error

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm using this script to cluster a set of 3D points using the kmeans matlab function but I always get this error "Empty cluster created at iteration 1". 
The script I'm using:

```
[G,C] = kmeans(XX, K, 'distance','sqEuclidean', 'start','sample');
```

XX can be found in this link [XX value](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rgatmmg2cx2z1cv/matlab_X.mat) and the K is set to 3
So if anyone could please advise me why this is happening.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is simply telling you that during the assign-recompute iterations, a cluster became empty (lost all assigned points). This is usually caused by an inadequate cluster initialization, or that the data has less inherent clusters than you specified.

Try changing the initialization method using the `start` option. [Kmeans](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html) provides four possible techniques to initialize clusters:

- sample: sample K points randomly from the data as initial clusters (default)
- uniform: select K points uniformly across the range of the data
- cluster: perform preliminary clustering on a small subset
- manual: manually specify initial clusters

Also you can try the different values of `emptyaction` option, which tells MATLAB what to do when a cluster becomes empty.

Ultimately, I think you need to reduce the number of clusters, i.e try `K=2` clusters.

---

I tried to visualize your data to get a feel for it:

```
load matlab_X.mat
figure('renderer','zbuffer')
line(XX(:,1), XX(:,2), XX(:,3), ...
    'LineStyle','none', 'Marker','.', 'MarkerSize',1)
axis vis3d; view(3); grid on
```

After some manual zooming/panning, it looks like a silhouette of a person:

[image: 3d_points]

You can see that the data of 307200 points is really dense and compact, which confirms what I suspected; the data doesnt have that many clusters.

---

Here is the code I tried:

```
>> [IDX,C] = kmeans(XX, 3, 'start','uniform', 'emptyaction','singleton');
>> tabulate(IDX)
  Value    Count   Percent
      1    18023      5.87%
      2    264690     86.16%
      3    24487      7.97%
```

Whats more, the entire points in cluster 2 are all duplicate points (`[0 0 0]`):

```
>> unique(XX(IDX==2,:),'rows')
ans =
     0     0     0
```

The other two clusters look like:

```
clr = lines(max(IDX));
for i=1:max(IDX)
line(XX(IDX==i,1), XX(IDX==i,2), XX(IDX==i,3), ...
    'Color',clr(i,:), 'LineStyle','none', 'Marker','.', 'MarkerSize',1)
end
```

[image: clustered points]

So you might get better clusters if you first remove duplicate points first...

---

In addition, you have a few outliers that might affect the result of clustering. Visually, I narrowed down the range of the data to the following intervals which encompasses most of the data:

```
>> xlim([-500 100])
>> ylim([-500 100])
>> zlim([900 1500])
```

Here is the result after removing dupe points (over 250K points) and outliers (around 250 data points), and clustering with `K=3` (best of out of 5 runs with the `replicates` option):

```
XX = unique(XX,'rows');
XX(XX(:,1) < -500 | XX(:,1) > 100, :) = [];
XX(XX(:,2) < -500 | XX(:,2) > 100, :) = [];
XX(XX(:,3) < 900 | XX(:,3) > 1500, :) = [];

[IDX,C] = kmeans(XX, 3, 'replicates',5);
```

with almost an equal split across the three clusters:

```
>> tabulate(IDX)
  Value    Count   Percent
      1    15605     36.92%
      2    15048     35.60%
      3    11613     27.48%
```

Recall that the default distance function is *euclidean distance*, which explains the shape of the formed clusters.

[image: final clustering]

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your kind assistance! I've used this code but the figure appears without clustering the points with different colors:  XX = unique(XX,'rows');
    XX(XX(:,1) < -500 | XX(:,1) > 100, :) = [];
    XX(XX(:,2) < -500 | XX(:,2) > 100, :) = [];
    XX(XX(:,3) < 900 | XX(:,3) > 1500, :) = [];
    [IDX,C] = kmeans(XX, 3, 'replicates',5);
    clr = lines(max(IDX));
    for ii=1:1
        line(XX(IDX==ii,1), XX(IDX==ii,2), XX(IDX==ii,3), ...
        'Color',clr(ii,:), 'LineStyle','none', 'Marker','.', 'MarkerSize',1)
        axis vis3d; view(3); grid on
    end

Comment: oops there was a typo (`for i=1:1` should have been `for i=1:K` where `K` is the number of clusters). Fixed now, see the edit :)

Comment: Thanks for this amazing solution, I really appreciate it. I'm wondering if you could assist me in doing another thing. Is it possible to remove the regions outside the big region? For example, in the above figure on the bottom right corner there are two regions of points not attached to the big region, I was wondering how can I remove the outlier regions? Many Thanks

Comment: @user1460166: perhaps another clustering algorithm like [DBSCAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) or [mean-shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean-shift) (density-based) might separate the points in the way you are expecting. Here are some other posts that will point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567515/find-connected-components-in-a-graph-in-matlab, http://stackoverflow.com/a/2303583/97160 .

Comment: You can always do this as a one-time interactive filtering using MATLAB's [brushing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/brush.html) capabilities. See this one for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7455390/97160

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but the problem is that I use this code on running frames of data, so I can't stop on each frame and manually edit it. That's why I'm asking if there is any other solution to apply it here? Many Thanks

Comment: figured as much :) You should look into the other clustering algorithms I mentioned. I think hierarchical clustering (which is implemented in the Statistics toolbox) might also work. See here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7133422/97160 . Experiment with the different linkage criteria

Comment: I've also tried this [class,type]=dbscanN(XX,3,[]); from the file found here but its taking avery long time https://www.dropbox.com/s/ugc7a0qyx5l3rav/DBSCANN.M

Comment: DO you have any suggestions? Many Thanks

Comment: Also I have a another small question, If I'm looping on more than XX matrices, the figures drawn from this clr = lines(max(IDX));
for i=1:max(IDX)
line(XX(IDX==i,1), XX(IDX==i,2), XX(IDX==i,3), ...
    'Color',clr(i,:), 'LineStyle','none', 'Marker','.', 'MarkerSize',1)
end; are displayed on top of each other, how can I clear the figure before each iteration? Thanks

Comment: DBSCAN should be used with *index acceleration*. Try the version in ELKI instead. I don't know if there is any index accelerated anything available in Matlab. Oh, and you should be fine *downsampling* this data without much loss.

Comment: @user1460166: I am not familiar with that implementation so I cant comment on it, but there is a note on Wikipedia about the [algorithm complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN#Complexity) and how it can be accelerated using a spatial indexing structure as Anony-Mousse mentioned. His remark about downsampling is also worth trying... As for you other comment, if you want to produce separate plots, you could either open new figures inside the loop, or clear existing ones using `clf` at the beginning of each iteration.

Comment: @Amro Thank you very much, I really appreciate your assistance

Comment: @Amro I'm asking if you could please check my question found here, thank you very much http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052326/join-neighbour-cluster-centroids-matlab

Comment: @Amro I want to rearrange the result IDX into 307200x1 or 640x480x1 to know in which cluster each pixel of the image belongs to. I don't know how can I do this as after clustering the IDX and XX become 37426 which is very good in performance but I don't know which pixel belongs to which cluster, do you have any suggestions please? Thanks

Comment: @Amro I want to do this as I want to know the nearest 2 points "pixels" between each cluster, I've posted a question regarding this here so I'd appreciate if you could have a look and let me know. Thanka alot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095542/nearest-point-between-two-clusters-matlab

Comment: @Amro I've replaced the zeros with NaN and the Kmeans run with no empty clusters, but this made me not use the `Unique` fn and increases the processing time. So I'm asking if you have any suggestions, as my target is to get the nearest point between two clusters "in any of them" as described in my question stated in my previous comment. Thanks

Comment: @user1460166: I posted an answer on your linked question

Answer (score 2):

If you are confident with your choice of "k=3", here is the code I wrote for not getting an empty cluster:

```
[IDX,C] = kmeans(XX,3,'distance','cosine','start','sample', 'emptyaction','singleton');

while length(unique(IDX))<3 ||  histc(histc(IDX,[1 2 3]),1)~=0
% i.e. while one of the clusters is empty -- or -- we have one or more clusters with only one member
[IDX,C] = kmeans(XX,3,'distance','cosine','start','sample', 'emptyaction','singleton');
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Amro [described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18013551/2093077) the reason clearly:

> It is simply telling you that during the assign-recompute iterations,
>   a cluster became empty (lost all assigned points). This is usually
>   caused by an inadequate cluster initialization, or that the data has
>   less inherent clusters than you specified.

But the other option that could help to solve this problem is `emptyaction`:

> Action to take if a cluster loses all its member observations.
>
> **`error`**: Treat an empty cluster as an error (default).
>
> **`drop`**: Remove any clusters that become empty. `kmeans` sets the corresponding return values in `C` and `D` to `NaN`. (for information
>   about  `C` and `D` see `kmeans` [documentioan page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html))
>
> **`singleton`**: Create a new cluster consisting of the one point furthest from its centroid.

---

**An example:**

Let’s run a simple code to see how this option changes the behavior and results of `kmeans`. This sample tries to partition 3 observations in 3 clusters while 2 of them are located at same point:

```
clc;
X = [1 2; 1 2; 2 3];
[I, C] = kmeans(X, 3, 'emptyaction', 'singleton');
[I, C] = kmeans(X, 3, 'emptyaction', 'drop');
[I, C] = kmeans(X, 3, 'emptyaction', 'error')
```

The first call with `singleton` option displays a warning and returns:

```
I =                               C =
 3                                 2     3
 2                                 1     2
 1                                 1     2
```

As you can see two cluster centroids are created at same location (`[1 2]`), and two first rows of `X` are assigned to these clusters.

The Second call with `drop` option also displays same warning message, but returns different results:

```
I =                               C =
 1                                 1     2
 1                               NaN   NaN
 3                                 2     3
```

It just returns two cluster centers and assigns two first rows of `X` to same cluster. I think most of the times this option would be most useful. In cases that observations are too close and we need as more cluster centers as possible, we can let MATLAB decide about the number. You can remove `NaN` rows form `C` like this:

```
C(any(isnan(C), 2), :) = [];
```

And finally the third call generates an exception and halts the program as expected.

`Empty cluster created at iteration 1.`