# Join neighbour cluster centroids Matlab

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have used K-means to cluster data into 8 different clusters using this `[X,C] = kmeans(XX, 8]` , this means I have 8 centroids where their locations is stored in `C` "example shown below X Y Z as coloumns". I want to connect the 8 centroids together where only the centroids of the clusters that are close to each other are connected "have borders between each other" while centroids of clusters that are not close to each other are not connected. So if anyone could please advise?

```
    C=
    -0.214560757496055  0.208243029984219   1.27200000000000
    -0.170247238295634  0.399735227073470   1.14600000000000
    -0.0129089952656497 0.410839908819919   1.22700000000000
    -0.244488865509381  0.0526915658425390  1.20200000000000
    -0.391215149921094  0.258634052253200   1.23600000000000
    -0.258542872172541  0.307469752761704   1.18100000000000
    -0.346834999123269  0.413056286165176   1.16100000000000
    -0.0885709275819744 0.278674381904261   1.23200000000000
```

I've used the as suggested but the centroids of some clusters but there are some unwanted connections that are constructed between centroids of non-neighbour clusters "e.g the centroid of the cluster top with the centroids of bottom clusters" as shown in the figure, so if you could please advise

```
X=C(:,1);
Y=C(:,2);
Z=C(:,3);
dt      = DelaunayTri(X,Y,Z); 
tetramesh(dt,'FaceColor', 'none');
```

[image: res]

Comment: Maybe have a look at Delaunay triangulation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunay.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as @Dan commented, you are looking for the Delaunay Triangulation, which is the dual of the Voronoi cells.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation for more details.

[image: From Wikipedia]

Image copyright information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Delaunay_Voronoi.png

Black dots are the cluster "centers". Black lines are the Delaunay Triangulation (which is probably what you are looking for) while the red lines and dots are the Voronoi diagram. The usual way to compute the Voronoi digaram actually is to first perform Deleaunay Triangulation, then intersect the orthogonals of nearby edges.

Comment: I've updated the question so if you could please check it please, Thanks alot

Comment: There seems to be an error in the computed triangulation, or the way you use it. `freeBoundary` does not seem appropriate; you actually want all the triangle edges.

Comment: I've updated the question where the problem now is that there are some unwanted connections that are constructed between centroids of non-neighbour clusters "e.g the centroid of the cluster top with the centroids of bottom clusters", could you please advise?

Comment: I believe that given the 3D nature of your data set, this amount of edges is to be expected. When rotating the image it should become evident why the edges are correct. Consider for example the bottom three, brown, yellow and cyan. The edge brown-cyan may appear to be redundant in 2D. But the yellow part is further in the front, while the brown and cyan are in the back, and the "extra" link is connecting the back. Similarly, green is sitting "atop" of all others, and thus rightfully connects to each of them.

Comment: If you want fewer edges, you could use PCA on your data set to reduce it to 2D, then project your centroids into this 2D space, and compute Delaunay triangulation there. Maybe `dt = DelaunayTri(X,Y);` will already to the job you want.